# Getting around paypal's repeated charges

Tags: banking, paypal, scams

Does anyone know of a bank that will decline (not overdraft) on electronic charges? Paypal keeps bouncing off my bank account after they screwed up and double charged me. I'm in the process of contesting the charges but they keep racking up the overdraft fees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your current bank will.  You can call them and put a hold on your account or possibly just make a note not to accept any charges from paypal until you say so.  Another option is to set up a line of credit with your bank.  Most banks will give you a line of credit (say $1000) that gets drawn on when you go below your checking account balance.  Of course, you will pay interest on that until you pay it down, but that is typically very small when compared with overdraft fees.

You might also temporarily disconnect paypal from your bank through paypal's interface until you get this figured out.

Different banks handle overdraft differently, and some are kinder to you than others.  That's one of those things you have to shop around for.  I don't have a specific recommendation for a bank.  Among my financial institutions, the one with the most customer-friendly policies is my credit union.  The least consumer friendly is probably paypal.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. After working with my bank the charges were recalled. As soon as my PP credit account is paid off, I'm closing out.